# VHDL : a problem with integer to std_logic_vector conversion

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

In my code `int_mm_add` is defined as an `integer` and `mm_add` is defined as `std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)`.

I try to convert from integer to std_logic_vector using:

```
mm_add <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(int_mm_add, mm_add'length));
```

`int_mm_add` is calculated using some other signals.
The integer calculation seems to work but the conversion not, for example when simulating:

```
int_mm_add = 1 converts to mm_add = "0000000000000X"
int_mm_add = 2 converts to mm_add = "000000000000X0"
```

Attached the part of the code that's relevant I think and a wave form snap:

- Here I tried to move the calculation directly into the conversion function instead of converting `int_mm_add` which would make the conversion be delayed by a clock:

```
process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            "something"
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            int_mm_add <= ((v_cnt / 8) * (2**8)) + (h_cnt / 8);
            mm_add <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(((v_cnt / 8) * (2**8)) + (h_cnt / 8), mm_add'length));
        end if;
end process;
```

[image: wave form that shows the conversion problem]

Comment: Whenever you see patterns like this `"00000000X0"`, it is likely that you are also driving the signal from somewhere else.  I suspect there is another process (or implicit process) that is driving all zeros on to `mm_add`.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Aha you were exactly right, in the top level file i accidentally drove (others => '0') into it. thank you!